Book trilogy read in 2006/2007 about a girl who is training to become a priestess
I believe one of the books started with an H, but it was not something I could pronounce. I read them back in 2006/2007. It starts out with a girl who is a novice in training to become a priestess. Her mother is a high priestess and she finds out that her mother is not her mother so she runs away and starts trying to find out who she is. One of the things that the woman who she believed was her mother said was that her actual mother died in childbirth and her father was a God. The God in these three books have black eyes and when she uses her Powers her eyes will go all black.
She does find her father‘s people, and she ends up, having to stop this evil organization of priest and priestesses. I also think somewhere that she rode a dragon. And in the end, after she defeats all of these evil people, her eyes are fully black. This whole story line happened within the three books, but I can’t exactly remember what order they were in.
